# reports.InvalidFilterException: [The duration NEXT_30_DAYS specified for the standard date filter is invalid.]

Tags: apex, date, reports-api

I try to create dynamic filtering on report using Report API.User can choose the date THIS_MONTH,LAST_30_DAYS.I set it at setDurationValue asn below :

```
        system.debug('@@@ getReportwithFilter date'+ dates);
        Reports.standardDateFilter stdDateFilter = reportMD.getStandardDateFilter();
        system.debug('@@@   Reports.standardDateFilter  '+ stdDateFilter );
        stdDateFilter.setColumn('CLOSE_DATE');
        stdDateFilter.setDurationValue(dates); //LAST_30_DAYS
        reportMd.setStandardDateFilter(stdDateFilter);

        reportOppo = ReportManager.getFilterReportResult(reportId,reportMd);
```

When I run the code ,I got exception like below :

> reports.InvalidFilterException: [The duration NEXT_30_DAYS specified
>   for the standard date filter is invalid.]

I read on Date Format LAST_N_DAYS:n [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) .But how to define 'N' value in Report API.

Comment: try this `LAST_N_DAYS:30`

Comment: @TusharSharma This works, I thought it only works in SQL .Can you put in Answer so I can accept this as Answer.

Comment: I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `NEXT_30_DAYS` you should use `LAST_N_DAYS:30`. This will solve your problem.